# Search a part of a file name

Tags: bash, shell

How can i get the name of the filename:

```
"2012_AppOwner_TestClass.csv"     --> "AppOwner"

"2012_AppOwner_V2_TestClass.csv"  --> "AppOwner_V2"
```

I have tried this:

echo "2012_AppOwner_TestClass.csv" | awk -F'[_.]' '{print $2}'

Whit this solution i get the part with the "App_Owner" but not the Version number in the second example!

Comment: can be the filename written in these two option only?

Comment: yes only in these two versions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like

```
>echo "2012_AppOwner_V2_TestClass.csv" | awk -F'[_.]' '{if (substr($3,1,1)=="V") print $2,$3; else print $2}'

result: AppOwner V2


>echo "2012_AppOwner_TestClass.csv" | awk -F'[_.]' '{if (substr($3,1,1)=="V") print $2,$3; else print $2}'

result: AppOwner
```

Comment: And when i want just the "TEEEEEEST" out of this line:      7387  02-01-16 13:24   Payload/TEEEEEST.app/embedded.mobileprovision

Comment: echo "Payload/TEEEEEST.app/embedded.mobileprovision " | cut -d"/" -f2|cut -d"." -f1